# How to get around issues with an LDAP load balancer

Tags: java, spring, authentication, ldap, load-balancing

My employer has setup round-robin LDAP load balancing.  This is causing issues with my web application (Java / Spring) that do user creation / maintenance.  For example, when a user registers, we will assign a temporary password and send them an email.  If they are quick to login with their temporary password, the new user may not have synced to the other LDAP servers.  This usually isn't an issue as the sync is faster than email and we can always add a delay before sending the email.  What is the most troubling is when they login with their temporary password.

Here is how the application handles the temp password login:

User logs in with the temp password.
Spring's `AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker` throws a `CredentialsExpiredException` which we catch in our `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.  We send them to a password setting page prompting them for their new password.  When they submit, we fire of the password change to LDAP and then attempt to reauthenticate them with their new password (we don't prompt them to reauthenticate, we just reuse the password they just submitted).  However, it is quite likely that the password change has not propagated to all the LDAP nodes behind the load balancer.  So, we go into a loop with a delay and retry the authentication.  Normally this works just fine but when the synchronization between the servers is bogged down, we can actually end up locking them out of their accounts.

Has anyone ran into this issue?  Any elegant workarounds (oxymoron?) that maintains the integrity of Spring Security (e.g. we don't want to totally hack the `AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker` to allow a user with expired credentials to get a valid `Principal`).

The guys who setup the company's LDAP infrastructure just suggested that we maintain our LDAP connection throughout the password change flow but they don't understand that doing something like this in a web app isn't advisable as you're just asking for connection leaks.

Comment: Many load-balancers support a "persistent" mode meaning that once an IP address connects through the load-balancer to a particular back-end server, the load-balancer connects that same IP address to the same back-end for several minutes or even hours. This mode is application-independent removing any concern about memory-leaks.

Comment: Yes, and our LDAP LB used to be setup that way but they explicitly disabled that functionality.  I'm dealing with a very rigid IT department who do things the way they want to do them.

Comment: If there is no way to force the user to a particular node after the password change AND the replication time to your replicas is potentially unbounded AND you don't want to do any custom programming of the authentication code, I don't think there is a solution. If you *could* customize the authentication code, you could do what Kerberos does: if a Kerberos client fails to authenticate against any of the nodes, as a last-resort it will try to authenticate against the master just in case there was a recent password change.